# Gratis Windows hotkey program for online gaming

Tags: windows, gratis, automation, keyboard-shortcuts

In "a certain online game", I have four different attacks, currently bound to keys X, C, V and B.

Using them in that order increases their effect. I.e X makes enemies more vulnerable to C, and so on (it doesn't wrap).

Each time I use a different one of these, it adds to a counter. When that counter reaches five, I can use a more powerful skill, mapped to N, up to 8 times.

So, for instance a good attack might be X C V B V N N N N N N N N. Rinse and repeat.

That sounds very simple, but the game has some bot detectors.  Is there a gratis program that can somewhat randomize these keystrokes? At the very least, a random delay between each keystroke, which looks convincingly human.

Also, I don't mind repeating some of the X C V B on sending only 5, 6, or 7 of the maximum 8 Ns.

E.g

```
optional  : X C V B V N N N N N N N N  
acceptable: X C V B V N N N N N N   
            X X C V V B V N N N N N N N N N
```

In fact, although using X C V B in that order is optimal, I don;t mind any 5 (or a few more) random selections, until 5 different have been used and the more powerful N can be used.

I am not sure if this is a separate question, as they as so closely related, feel free to edit. But, I hope that one auto-key program can handle both.

I also have skill buffs, which add or enhance skills. Each buff lasts for X seconds, then cannot be activated for a further Y seconds, where X and Y vary per skill. I would like to be able to automatically activate these skills and keep them active by reactivating after the cool-down period. Again, a little randomness, would be nice, as much as 10% would be a major improvement, as I invariably forget to refresh my buffs.

On reflection, the second part of this question is more valuable than the first, but I am too lazy to edit it :-)

It should, of course, be possible to toggle these key sequences. Bonus if they can function per app.

Gamers - what do you use?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried: https://www.autohotkey.com/, you can do almost anything 
(as far as your programming skill reaches. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give a chance to PoweToys, it has several tools and one of the is:
[Keyboard Manager](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/tree/master/src/modules/keyboardmanager) that allows you to remap almost everything.

[image]

You can download it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/)